# Spaghetti stack in C

Tags: c, data-structures

Does anybody know where I can find an example of a [Spaghetti stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_stack) written in C?

Comment: +1 for one of the most weird data structures, useful almost only in symbols table stacks for compilation..

Comment: @Jack: "almost" aside, spaghetti stacks are also very useful in implementing continuations.

Comment: @outis can you elaborate the uses of Spaghetti stack because I don't know why this data structure is used?

Comment: @Jerky: Outside of asking for clarification on a question or answer, comments shouldn't be used to ask additional questions. For one thing, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. If you have questions beyond what was originally asked, first check on the appropriate SE site whether your question has already been asked, and post a new question if not. Since you're asking about data structure concepts (rather than implementation details involving code), try [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

It should be something similar to that:

```
struct stack_item;

struct stack_item
{
    stack_item *parent;
    void *ptr_data;
};

stack_item *stack_pointer = null;

void push(stack_item *item)
{
    if (stack_pointer == null)
        item->parent = null;
    else
        item->parent = cur; 

stack_pointer = item;
}

/* like push but doesn't update cur stack item to the one pushed, just add a child */
void push_parallel(stack_item *item)
{
    if (stack_pointer == null)
    {
        stack_pointer = item;
        item->parent = null;
    }
    else
        item->parent = stack_pointer;
}

stack_item *pop()
{
    if (stack_pointer == null)
    {
        printf("error: stack is empty.\r\n");
        return null;
    }

    stack_item *current = stack_pointer;
    stack_pointer = current->parent;

    return current;
}
```

Mind that a *spaghetti stack* is useful when you want to keep references of things that you pop out of the stack, having many parallel *linked list* that end to a common root. So you have to keep references of item you pop out because you need to traverse them in a *bottom-up* way from the leaf to the root, and of course using a different leaf node will produce a different linked list that has elements in common with other lists that start from other leaves..

Comment: shouldn't the push_parallel function return a pointer to the top of the stack?

Comment: cur is just an error due to stack_pointer that was called in a different way, I fixed it. For the push_parallel function it depends, the fact is that a spaghetti stack doesn't really have ONE top of the stack but many according from where you start to visit it, usually you have to care about references outside the stack by yourself.